# CakePHP saveMany Internal Server Error 500

Tags: php, sql-server, cakephp

I'm trying to save **N** records with CakePHP 3.6, in which it kind of works.
I'm using SQL Server, and it's all out-of-the-box installation, I just changed the connection credentials.

I have this endpoint called

> store/N

in which **N** is the number of records, and the code is the following:

```
public function store($records)
    {
        $this->autoRender = false;
        $examplesTable  = TableRegistry::get('efsc_examples');

        $values = array();
        $i = 0;
        while($i < $records) {
            $example                 = array();
            $example['name']         = 'A New Article ';
            $example['observation']  = ('Observation ');
            $example['code']         = '0000004';

            $entity = $examplesTable->newEntity($example);
            $examplesTable->save($entity, array('callbacks'=>false));
            $i++;
        }
        return $this->response->withStringBody("");
    }
```

If I store 1 record it works, but If I store 100 records it doesn't work.
By not working, I mean it retrieves Internal Server Error 500, but it **STORES** in the database;

But the most weired case is, if I try with 1000 it works, without retrieving Internal Server Error 500;

I can't figure it out, and in my errors log, I have nothing;

Anyone kind to help?

Comment: Look into PHP's/webserver's error log for more details.

Comment: @JiriHrazdil Thank you for your response, I have no errors in my log file; Only related to mod_fcgid. Can that be related?

Comment: do you have debug mode on?

Comment: @arilia yes I do

Comment: I don't really know what you mean by "traditional database operations", but CakePHP surely allows you to go low level if you want to, you don't _have_ to use `save/saveMany`, you can [**generate insert queries directly**](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/query-builder.html#inserting-data) if you neded to, and you can also [**compose raw queries**](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/database-basics.html#executing-queries).

Comment: echo your query in a loop and try to print that query on the screen, Run your script with 500 records set and check the query where it is failing